# Failed building wheel for psutil on macOS

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, psutil

## Problem

I am trying to install psutil using pip so I ran `pip install psutil` but I receive the following error message:

```
Failed building wheel for psutil
Running setup.py clean for psutil
```

---

## What I have tried

It seems like the problem is occurring during setup.py: `Building wheel for psutil (setup.py) ... error`.

I have tried running :

```
xcode-select --install
```

but I get the following error message:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

---

I have also tried:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Both work fine but even after restarting the terminal, I see no change.

---

And finally, I have tried running:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Which also makes no difference.

Comment: Please post the complete log of the `pip install psutil` command.

Comment: The error was very long so I attached it using google drive.

Comment: The log is still stripped, but I suppose this is the same issue as [#1632](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1632). Try downloading an older SDK (e.g. 10.9 from [here](https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs/releases)), unpack and install via `CFLAGS="-isysroot /path/to/MacOSX10.9.sdk" pip install psutil`. If you don't succeed, I can upload the wheels built on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, for directing me to that site. It actually turned out that I had 2 versions of the sdk installed so all I had to do was delete the older one and that got it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just typed:

```
sudo open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs
```

into my terminal and it turns out that I have 2 versions of the Command Line SDK installed so it looked like this:

```
MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX10.15.sdk
MacOSX10.15.sdk
MacOSX10.14.sdk
```

I then just deleted the older MacOSX10.14.sdk and everything starting working correctly.

Solution found here: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/1632#issuecomment-564800186